# Escape characters being displayed in text in php app

Tags: php

I have a legacy php app that I am supporting.  This is a super simple app, part of which is a text field.  I am having an issue where if the users use either single or double quotes, they show up with escape characters.

The funny thing is that locally, the app looks great, and does not display the escape characters.  However, on the server (CPanel) the users DO see the escape characters.  Part of the code uses `str_replace` to remove characters, so its possible that the function is not working properly on the server?

I am running php version 5.3.10 locally and on Cpanel I am running 5.3.22.  Any server side settings that would cause this not work on the server?

Comment: Does the server have "magic quotes" enabled?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: P.S. CPanel is just an administration software, it has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: Good call Rocket. magic quotes in off on my local install, but on on the server. I'll turn it off on the server and see what effect I get.

Comment: OK, you da man Rocket! I turned magic quotes off at the server level and that did the trick. Hopefully it will not blow anything up on any of the apps.

Comment: Yeah, I hope nothing was actually relying on that.  Check your MySQL queries and make sure they are all escaped safely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has ["magic quotes"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.  This automatically escapes all `'` and `"` that come in via `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

It's suggested you disable this "feature".

PHP 5.3 has deprecated it and PHP 5.4 has removed it.

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php